# DB2 9.7 - Find rows inserted by a specific trigger

Tags: trigger, db2

We are auditing a table `TRANSACTIONS` that inserts a row in `HISTORY_TRANSACTIONS` when specific columns are changed. These inserts happen through a number of triggers defined on `TRANSACTIONS` table. Is it possible to find out which trigger inserted a specific record in `HISTORY_TRANSACTIONS` ? (seems impossible, but I wanted to confirm that no system tables could achieve this as well?)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption – there is nothing done at the database level that would track the source of a row.  You would need to modify your history table definition and trigger logic to add this kind of tracking.

Comment: That being said...I think there is some audit logging you can turn on in DB2 but I do not know to what extent it logs. I believe that by default this is off.

Comment: Auditing (at least on DB2 for LUW) would be able to track the actual insert statement, but because triggers are compiled in to the actual `insert` statement it would not be possible to identify which trigger caused the particular action.

Comment: that's a bummer....